# In x86 assembly, is ESP decremented twice after a call and then push, before data is saved on the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, push, call

Long story short, I'm studying a book titled "The 8088 and 8086 Microprocessors" by Singh and Triebel, to learn **old** assembly for those specific CPUs. Now, the computer I'm practicing on is my main computer, which I recently built, so the registers are bigger.

That said, the book (which I find extremely helpful) says that the call label operand causes the address of the instruction following the call to be placed on the stack, and THEN `SP` is decremented by 2 (`ESP`, and decremented by 4 on my CPU). In some code I'm studying, a call operand is immediately followed by a `push`. When the CPU encounters a `push`, the book states that `SP` is decremented by two (again, `ESP` is decremented by 4 on my CPU).

```
; ESP=0xffffd840 right now
call iprint
mov eax, 0Ah

iprint:
push eax ; say eax contains 1
```

Now, say `ESP=0xffffd840` before the call. The address of `EIP` is saved on the stack (the address of the instruction that follows the `CALL` operand). Then `ESP` is decremented by 4. At this point, `ESP=0xffffd83c`. Then the push operand is encountered. Going by what the book says, the stack pointer is decremented first, and then the contents of the register are pushed onto the stack. So now `ESP=0xffffd838` and 1 is pushed onto the stack.

```
If it helps:
Stack addr  Contents
********** ********
0xffffd840  address of mov eax, 0Ah
0xffffd83c  ?
0xffffd838  1
```

Now, my question is, is `0xffffd83c` skipped? According to the book, `ESP` is decremented after saving the next instruction after the `call`, and then before data is put on the stack from the `push`, it's decremented again.

I've been debugging a similar scenario for a while now, paying close attention to the values of the registers, but I just can't tell if the debugger adheres to what the book says (decrementing before doing an operation, or after).

Is this because in some cases a parameter is given after `RET` in a subroutine, causing the stack pointer to increment? If the stack pointer is indeed decremented twice before having data put on it, this is the only reason I can see.

Could someone please confirm or explain this if I have this wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `call <address>` is like: `push eip` `jmp <address>`, so in your case if `esp` is `0xffffd840` is ahead of `call`, the returning address of next instruction is pushed to `0xffffd83c` (Because the pseudo "`push eip`" will first decrement the `esp` to create new top of stack, then it will store the current value of `eip` there (BTW, the `eip` already points at next instruction, as the fetch+decode instruction phase of `call` was finished, so it is actually the value which will be needed for `ret`).

You can also in debugger view memory. And "stack" is just ordinary memory. So if you have `esp` equal to `0xffffd840`, you can open for example memory view at `0xffffd824`, and you will see 32 bytes of stack memory, with the 28 bytes not-used-yet and last 4 bytes being current "top of the stack".

I'm using group of 4 bytes everywhere, as that's the native size of CPU "word" (`dword` in x86 terminology, `word` is 16 bit only) in 32b protected mode. IIRC you can still enforce the CPU to do `push ax` or use `sub/add esp,immediate` to even move it by single byte, but usually it involves performance penalties, and in 64b modes several calling conventions even require 16 byte alignment, so I would recommend to stick with +-4 `esp` operations in 32b mode.

But if your book is about 8086, you may want to use `dosbox` to emulate the old DOS 16 bit environment, to save you some platform specific problems in the beginning. Although maybe you should instead find some 32/64 bit recent book for your OS, as the 32b protected mode on x86 is much easier to learn (only the graphics output is not as straightforward as it was back in DOS era, but if you will mix your asm files with C++ "loader", which would for example initialize some window surface as ARGB memory array, you can pass that pointer down to the asm routines and toy around with pixels, in the same simple way, how the old 320x200 "mode 13h" in DOS worked. Even easier (no palette and no 64k segment limits).

Comment: In your first paragraph, you say that esp is decremented first, but the book says the address of the next instruction in EIP is saved first, before ESP is decremented. And the GUI debuggers I've used are problematic. I've been trying to view the stack this whole time, which would have cleared things up much easier lol.

Comment: @s0s when in doubt, just read the original Intel docs... as I'm always lazy to link to those big pdfs, I will just put here the online simplified copy (sometimes contains tiny inaccuracies, but in this case much more accurate than your book): http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html I believe the author of the book probably didn't pay enough attention to the formulation, as it's kinda obvious how new values are pushed to stack, so it would make very little sense to do it in some other fashion just for `call`. So probably they didn't realize the description is in wrong order.

Comment: @s0s btw, I use `edb` debugger, as it reminds me of "turbo debugger" (old DOS era debugger from Borland) and it's lacking support for some more complex debug symbol support/etc is not a problem for my tiny asm experiments. But I had to compile it from sources on my laptop (Ubuntu distro), it's not in packaged. If you would ever want to do serious debugging in NIX world, it's probably best to bite the bullet and learn to use pure `gdb`, as it's a very powerful tool. But I don't like its commands, so instead I just don't do bugs, and use unit testing, avoiding debugging as long as possible. :)

Comment: Ah, Borland for DOS. Those were the days lol. For 'nix asm, I use gdb, or ddd, a front-end for gdb. Thanks for your help! :D And yeah, an 803 page, 57MB pdf manual is pretty heavy lol. That link was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Sorry, my previous answer was wrong for your first question. My x86 is rusty. The best way to check is to debug your program. Here's a similar one (NASM syntax):

```
global _start

section .text

test:
push eax
pop eax
ret

_start:
mov eax, 1
call test
```

You can compile this on Linux as follows:

```
$ nasm -f elf32 -g test.s && ld -m elf_i386 -g test.o
```

Now let's use GDB to debug it:

```
$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
```

Disassemble `_start` function to see its addresses

```
(gdb) disas _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x08048063 <+0>: mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048068 <+5>: call   0x8048060 <test>
End of assembler dump.
```

Put a breakpoint at the start

```
(gdb) b *0x08048063
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048063
```

And run it!

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/yasin/Downloads/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048063 in _start ()
```

Check ESP starting value

```
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xffffce00   0xffffce00
```

And put a breakpoint on `test` function.

```
(gdb) disas test
Dump of assembler code for function test:
   0x08048060 <+0>: push   %eax
   0x08048061 <+1>: pop    %eax
   0x08048062 <+2>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *0x08048060
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8048060
```

Let's continue

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x08048060 in test ()
```

Ok, stopped at start of `test`, before `push`, let's check ESP value and its contents

```
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xffffcdfc   0xffffcdfc
(gdb) x /1xw $esp
0xffffcdfc: 0x0804806d
```

It has been decremented by 4 and the call return value pushed there. Let's put another breakpoint after `push` and see what happens.

```
(gdb) b *0x08048061
Breakpoint 3 at 0x8048061
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, 0x08048061 in test ()
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xffffcdf8   0xffffcdf8
(gdb) x /1xw $esp
0xffffcdf8: 0x00000001
```

It has decremented ESP by 4 and pushed 1. So now stack looks like this

```
(gdb) x /2xw $esp
0xffffcdf8: 0x00000001  0x0804806d
```

So resuming: what you were missing is that `CALL` also behaves like `PUSH`: it decrements `ESP` by 4 before pushing the value into the stack.

And for the rest of the questions:

> decremented by 4 on my CPU

Assemblers usually default to 32 bits and not 16 bits, that's why it is decrementing 4 bytes and not 2. You can force your assembler to use 16-bit instructions instead.

> In some code I'm studying, a call operand is immediately followed by a
>   push

In fact that is the common case, it is called the function/routine entry protocol.

> I've been debugging a similar scenario for a while now, paying close
>   attention to the values of the registers, but I just can't tell if the
>   debugger adheres to what the book says.

The step by step run I've made should have clarified how to check register and memory/stack values. If you have any further questions about this, let me know.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally skipped over the line in which you typed your answer, before I added the next post. I have deleted it. Darn ADHD lol Thanks! :D