# Why %esp gets changed imexplitcitly?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, gdb

The title is actually my second problem.
2 problems arose when I was learning the CSAPP 2nd edition, chapter 3. There're 2 relative simple files. Here's the first one:

```
    // code.c
    int accum = 0;

    int sum(int x, int y)
    {
         int     t = x + y;
         accum += t;
         return t;
    }
```

The second one:

```
    // main.c
    int main() {
         return sum(1, 3);
    }
```

I used gcc to compile them, following the book. In order to get a 32-bit program, I added an -m32 option(Mine is 64-bit Ubuntu):

```
   $ gcc -m32 -O1 -O prog code.c main.c
```

Things were good up to this far. But when I disassembled it using GDB, it really confused me. I got the following result that conflicted with what the book says:

```
    (gdb) disas sum
    Dump of assembler code for function sum:
        0x080483ed <+0>:    mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
        0x080483f1 <+4>:    add    0x4(%esp),%eax
        0x080483f5 <+8>:    add    %eax,0x804a020
        0x080483fb <+14>:   ret    
    End of assembler dump.
    (gdb) disas main
    Dump of assembler code for function main:
        0x080483fc <+0>:    push   %ebp
        0x080483fd <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
        0x080483ff <+3>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
        0x08048402 <+6>:    sub    $0x10,%esp
        0x08048405 <+9>:    movl   $0x3,0x4(%esp)
        0x0804840d <+17>:   movl   $0x1,(%esp)
        0x08048414 <+24>:   call   0x80483ed <sum>
        0x08048419 <+29>:   leave  
        0x0804841a <+30>:   ret    
   End of assembler dump.
```

Now here are my problems:

1. Why isn't there any saving %ebp or moving %esp when calling the function *sum* as the book describes? Or is *sum* inlined by the compiler?
2. The value 3 & 1 were already stored in the M[%esp + 4] & M[%esp], respectively. And after calling the *sum*, there's no instruction that alters the value stored in %esp. But inside the *sum*, the first instruction retrieves M[%esp + 8], which is actually 3(I set the breakpoint using GDB &checked the value), while the M[%esp + 4] stores the value 1. How come? Later I set 2 breakpoints:

   ```
    (gdb) break *0x08048414
    (gdb) break sum
   ```

Then I found the value stored in %esp was different at these 2 breakpoints:

```
     Breakpoint 6, 0x08048414 in main ()
     (gdb) print $esp
     $8 = (void *) 0xffffd020
     (gdb) continue
     Continuing.

     Breakpoint 5, 0x080483ed in sum ()
     (gdb) print $esp
     $9 = (void *) 0xffffd01c
```

Why would this occur?

Comment: What about `push`, `pop`, `call`, `ret`?

Comment: It seems weird that this code compiled successfully because `sum()` is not defined in `main.c`. Is this the actual code you compiled?

Comment: @LiranFunaro I think with C and bad compiler settings it'll just warn "undefined, I'll assume it returns int and actually takes these arguments"

Comment: There was recently this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44129645/4271923 ... may help with `call/ret` vs stack understanding (but you should also read [`call/ret` instruction details](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html)). The "`ebp` = frame-pointer" is just convention, it is not mandatory. The C++ compiler in certain optimization modes may not do that for better performance. *"Or is sum inlined by the compiler?"* - in your `main` disassembly is `0x08048414 <+24>:   call   0x80483ed <sum>` => definitely not inlined, if there's `call`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't there any saving %ebp or moving %esp when calling the function sum as the book describes?

You might have enabled option to omit frame pointer, most probably with -Ox compiler option. You can force GCC to still keep it with -fno-omit-frame-pointer GCC command line argument:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O

> But inside the sum, the first instruction retrieves M[%esp + 8], which is actually 3, while the M[%esp + 4] stores the value 1. How come?

Call instruction pushes eip register to the stack and moves esp. You compiled it in 32 bit mode, so the offset is 4 bytes.